# Exporting data to INSERT INTO script using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to export a table into a .sql script containing INSERT statements using T-SQL.

There are many public posts about using SSMS and clicking on things. I must create something that can be scripted. Can T-SQL export a file containing INSERT statements?

Comment: Answers don't go in the question body. It has been correctly closed as a duplicate.